# How to upgrade siddhi jars version in w.r.t wso2sp worker container?

Tags: wso2, siddhi, stream-processing, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am trying to change the jars inside wso2 4.4.0 worker container to the latest version instead the default one

I have tried to:

1. replace the jar inside the container
2. change the jar before building the base image and also changing the bundle in DEPENDENCIES file.

But I'm getting the same error. 
I have replaced siddhi-io-http-1.2.0.jar to siddhi-io-http-2.1.2jar

Error:

> No extension exist for source:http-call-response

Answer (score 0):

SP 4.4.0 has Siddhi 4x as the core engine.Only siddhi-io-http 1.x versions are compatible.

Comment: how can I use siddhi-io-http 2.X versions with SP 4.4.0? Is it compatible ?

Comment: WSO2 SP only supports Siddhi 4. However, Siddhi.io supports Siddhi 5. Siddhi.io now comes as a cloud-native stream processor, https://siddhi.io. Migration is simple.   You can try out the latest release in https://github.com/siddhi-io/distribution/releases/tag/v5.1.0